# Changed GitHub password, can no longer push code on terminal. How do I fix this?

Tags: git, github

I'm looking to update and login to Github on my terminal. I had suspicious activity on my account so I had to change my password and now when I'm trying to push my code out for my project it says:

Remote: invalid username or password

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: That error means your git client software is using your Github user account’s password instead of using a dedicated SSH key or OpenID token. **You should never use your Github account password with git client software**.

Comment: As Dai said, don't use passwords, neither in your computer, by using the SSH (pretty easy to set up and use) you're way more secure, and if anyone accesses your computer you just remove the SSH public key in GitHub, and no one will be able to access your repo or account.

Comment: Oh wow, this is good to know. I'm still a student and haven't heard that this wasn't the right way to do things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+forget+credentials

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+reset+credentials